# Errorbar of same variable do not get conditionally seperated when using facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, errorbar

I have the following dataset:

[Figure: dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ0bG.png)

I want to create three bar plots side by side using facet. I have the following code in R:

```
  ggplot(nod.stat, aes(fill=Fix, x=Fix, y=mean)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position=position_dodge(width=0.9)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes( ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se), position = position_dodge(width = 0.90), width=0.2) +
  facet_wrap(.~variable, scales='free')
```

But this keeps adding all three SE from same Fix condition like the following graph: 
[Figure: output bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCLI7.png)

How can I make sure that there is only one errorbar respective to each bar?

Comment: You seem to have three rows of data per bar (with different `se`), so you are getting multiple error bars per bar. For example, Fix=-, variable = Total Nodules has 3 rows, with 3 different `se`s, leading to 3 bars. If you only want one error bar per bar, you will have to filter your dataframe to only have one row per bar (with the `se` you have selected)

Comment: Thanks, I will try to change dataframe format.

Comment: Thanks, I removing the extra two rows per bar helped. It was a merging error!